# Binary numbers challenge

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge

I don't know if this is exactly refactoring but I recently completed a [programming challenge](http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=20) to learn more about Ruby's iterators. However, I feel that the code is extremely "un-Ruby like". Would anyone have any suggestions as to how I could improve it?

```
numbers = []
binary = []
binary_count = 0

File.open('decimals.txt').each_line do |line|
  numbers.push line.chomp
end

numbers.each do |number|
  binary.push number.to_i.to_s(2)
end

binary.each do |binary_num|
 binary_count += binary_num.count("1") 
end

puts binary_count
```

Yes, I know it's a basic problem. It took me roughly five minutes to complete but it was more about just getting the syntax of the iterators down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not open a stream instead use IO.readlines and enum methods:

```
puts File.readlines("decimals.txt").reduce(0) { |total, line| total += line.chomp.to_i.to_s(2).count("1") }
```

Comment: no need to `chomp` before `to_i`. `"123\n".to_i => 123`

Comment: Why would you recommend IO.readlines and enum methods as opposed to a stream?

Comment: IO.readlines returns array of lines as your first block does. it also ensures the stream is closed and  its native implementation is more optimized than the Ruby code. It is very easy to read in the code and explains the intention better. Enumerable methods are the coolest part of Ruby. Beside coolness, there is no point to keep 2 arrays + 1 stream in the memory for no reason. You have 3 star actors in the cast who never show up in the movie. It is much easier to understand shorter, but not too short, code. Only thing that I do not like is `to_i.to_s(2)` which would be better: `to_binary`

Comment: By the way, you should watch [The Enumerable Module or How I fell in Love with Ruby](http://confreaks.com/videos/607-cascadiaruby2011-the-enumerable-module-or-how-i-fell-in-love-with-ruby) if you have not yet

Comment: Ok thanks! That helps a lot. Any other recommendations for screencasts on Ruby/RoR to watch?